# Hide Function parameter from URL when a request is made

Tags: php, url, cakephp, routes

I want to hide the action parameters from my url when a request to a particular action is made. For instance,

```
<?php 

   echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'controllerName', 'action' => 'actionName', parameter1, $parameter2)); 

 ?>
```

The above code will generate url:

```
  controllerName/actionName/1/123
```

What I want to achieve is, when users clicks on such urls, the `param1 (= 1)` and `param2 (= 123)` shouldn't be visible to him, and link should be like,

```
  controllerName/actionName    /* no attribute visible */
```

Is this possible? How I can achieve this, I was reading about [Routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html), but couldn't get how to achieve this !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of search and trying many things I ended up with this solution.

Generating the link, and binding action name and parameter as data:

```
<a class="blue viewDetailButton" data-action='<?= $detail["controllerActionName"] ?>' data-request_id='<?= $detail["request_id"] ?>' >
```

Now, wrote a jquery script that will trigger on click event and do a post request (submit form as post with attribute as data):

```
$(document).on("click", ".viewDetailButton", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var url = '<?= $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'requests', 'action'=>null)) ?>/'+$(this).data("action");
        var form = $('<form action="' + url + '" method="post">' +
          '<input type="text" name="id" value="'+$(this).data("request_id")+'" />' +
          '</form>');
         $(form).submit();
  }) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a POST request instead of GET, or use `pushState` to set the browser's URL bar to whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks. But how we can do post request (in cakephp) when user click on a url ? should I use CURL for that? or is there any better alternative..? Searched but didn't find anything appropriate with this.

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::postLink

Comment: `$this->Form->postLink(__('View'), array('controller'=>'controllerName', 'action' => 'actionName', $param), null)`    did this ! but unfortunately the param is still showing in the url. What could be the issue ?